# How to Add one column based on the values of another column AND display into another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

[image: Excel Image]

I need to add all column G values together for each Value in column C (ndc) and display them into another sheet listing just NDC and then Total next to it. How would I go about doing that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a pivot table for this.

Click anywhere in your table, select Insert -> Pivot Table. Create the pivot table in another sheet. When you are shown the new pivot table, you will see a window pop up on the right called "Field List". Drag NDC to the "Row Labels" and the TotalQty to the "Values" section (if it says "COUNT Of TotalQty", click it, choose Value Properties...and change it to SUM).

Comment: I tried messing with PivotTable and couldn't get it to do what I wanted. I didn't realize I had to click Value Properties and change it to sum. That worked perfect. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it working :)